# How to destructure a vector efficiently

Tags: rust

I am trying to find an efficient way to destructure the vector in rust. Assigning the values on the index to the respective variable. I have been through the documentations and was not able to find the answer.

```
let (frequency, samplingrate, samples, slope, duration, steps) = (input[0], input[1], input[2], input[3], input[4], input[5]);
```

Comment: That isn't really what a `Vec` was designed to be used for, a use case like that would be better suited for a struct.

Comment: If you can, express that as a tuple instead.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Rust name for this is [Slice patterns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html#slice-patterns).

But slice patterns can not be used irrefutably, except with an array. That is, you can't just do something like this:

```rust
let [a, b, c] = v[..3];
```

Because the compiler can't prove that the resulting slice is 3 elements long, even though it may be obvious to us.

Instead, you need to tell the compiler to convert the given slice into an array instead, like so:

```rust
let [a, b, c]: &[_; 3] = v[..3].try_into().unwrap();
```

Because array sizes are known at compile time, the compiler can prove that such an operation is infallible.

Here's what the code should look like for your case:

```rust
let [frequency, samplingrate, samples, slope, duration, steps]: &[_; 6] = input[..6].try_into().unwrap();
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=94743a95203a7c10ad9de1277e775cbb)

Comment: Or via a `match` expression. In a `match` expression, we have the added benefit that the "failed" branch can contain a `panic!` with a nice, detailed message.

Comment: True, same with `if let`, but in an instance where the programmer knows it to be infallible, there isn't much use in explicitly handling the other case. For instance, `input[..6]` would panic before we'd ever reach that.